# How to send email Asynchronously in ASP.Net using Background Thread inside a foreach Statement

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, multithreading, email, asynchronous

Sending Single mail using Thread is working fine and very fast.

```
Thread TDemail = new Thread(delegate ()
{
    cm.SendEmail(cm);
});
```

This is my code for sending multiple emails. I want to send multiple email Asynchronously using Background Thread inside a foreach Statement. Any help is highly appreciable.

```
MailFunction cm = new MailFunction();
foreach (var clist in NewslettersList)
{
    cm.To = clist.NewsletterEmail;
    try
    {
        cm.SendEmail(cm);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the mail function?

Comment: `SendMail` is a synchronous method, your thread actually blocks when executes that method. In order to have really asynchronous method, you need to change `SendMail` method in the first place.

Comment: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create an **asynchronous ForEach** extension like this

```
 public static async Task ForEachAsync<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items, Func<T, Task> func)
        {
            foreach (var value in items)
            {
                await func(value);
            }
        }
```

the use that to send your mails asynchronously like this

```
MailFunction cm = new MailFunction();
await NewslettersList.ForEachAsync(async clist =>
            {
                cm.To = clist.NewsletterEmail;
                await cm.SendEmail(cm);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find a perfect blog [post from Scott Hanselman](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx)

Easiest way to do you need to is a `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem`:

```
HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem(ct =>
{
    var cm = new MailFunction();
    foreach (var clist in NewslettersList)
    {
        cm.To = clist.NewsletterEmail;
        try
        {
            cm.SendEmail(cm);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
    }
});
```

Also you probably need to handle the exception properly, don't just catch it. As for `Task.Run`, you can find a lot of questions here in SO like "why didn't my `Task` finish it's job". Direct usage of `TPL` is considered bad practice, as `ASP.NET` has it's own thread pool managing logic, and threads can be suspended after handling the request.

Answer (score -1):

Use the Task API. Do not use Threads. The Task API scheduler will reuse background threads when emails are sent out.

```
MailFunction cm = new MailFunction();
foreach (var clist in NewslettersList)
{
    cm.To = clist.NewsletterEmail;
    Task.Run(() => 
    {
        try {
            cm.SendEmail(cm);
        } catch (Exception) {
        }
    });                     
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's working. But as per the blog - http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html using Task.Factory.StartNew is very dangerous. I tried Task.Run and it's working perfect.

Comment: correct, edited to use Task.Run()  would help if you accepted the answer. @WMAtm care to epxand on the comment, the solution seems fine for his context - he abstracted all the other stuff.